# How to avoid WebDriver getting stuck while waiting for Google Ads or Google Analytics to load?

Tags: selenium, google-analytics, webdriver, adsense

I'm using `Selenium WebDriver` (C# library) for UI automation. The web app uses google ads and google analytics on most of pages.

When I run the tests after a while (about 50 tests executed) all tests get stuck and eventualy fail while waiting for google ads and analytics to load.

- Has anyone had this problem?
- How would you work around this issue?

But before you answer 'create a build just for tests without google ad scripts' lets say its not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

- use the [hosts file trick](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) to block the google ad servers (but this would block them for all users of that PC, not just the selenium tests)
- set up an http proxy such as squid, and configure it to return empty content from those sites.
- use a custom firefox profile that uses NoScript to block those sites

Comment: First solution is acceptable since I'll setup VM just for auto-tests. But I'd appreciate an example of third solution. Can you show me some snippet or a link to an example of that?

Comment: Can't find much about how to do it Selenium 2, but http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver ought to help (you'd create a profile and then set `webdriver.firefox.profile` during the test setup)